# write the exact node to another file

Tags: xml, python-3.4

I am using python 3.4, using entree to parse a xml file. 
I search the xml file to find particular nodes and then I need to write them to a file.
The problem I have is that the node copied to the new file is not exactly the same as the original one.
 for example: the node 
[image]

is written to the new file as

[image]

for writing I used:

with open('predicate.tex', 'a') as f1:
          f1.write(str(etree.tostring(myNode, pretty_print=True)))

Any advice how to copy the exact node to another file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok I am going to answer my question in the way that I solved it in my program. I found out that a node from xml file can't be the same in a tex file.

So To have the same node simply I build a new xml document and append the wanted nodes to the new xml tree. This can be done as explained here:

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#building-xml-documents

Thanks